# Particles Hair - Size params

Tags: particles

I study particles hair. And I can not see how the size param affects at particles. When I change it all stay the same.

Can you say or show me how does it affect?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to go these steps:

1. Set Particle Properties > Render > Render As : Object
2. Set object.
3. Play with controls.

I found the answer [here](https://developer.blender.org/T76731).